# How to calculate pass% & insert into a column in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading data from HDFS into a spark dataframe. Based on the `Status` value I need to insert a value `1/0/-1` for `Passed/Failed/Aborted` into `quality` column Or do we have any possibility of calculating Pass %.

```py
df = sparkSession.read.json(hdfsPath)

+-----------+---------+
|         ID|Status   |
+-----------+---------+
|Tsz3650419c|   Passed|
|Tsz3650420c|   Failed|
|Tsz3650421c|   Passed|
|Tsz3650422c|   Passed|
|Tsz3650423c|  Aborted|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If data looks like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, when

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("Tsz3650419c", "Passed"), ("Tsz3650420c", "Failed"),
    ("Tsz3650421c", "Passed"), ("Tsz3650422c", "Passed"),
    ("Tsz3650423c", "Aborted")
]).toDF("ID", "Status")
```

define levels:

```py
levels = ["Passed", "Failed", "Aborted"]
exprs = [
    avg((col("Status") == level).cast("double")*100).alias(level)
    for level in levels]

df.groupBy("ID").agg(*exprs).show()
# +-----------+------+------+-------+
# |         ID|Passed|Failed|Aborted|
# +-----------+------+------+-------+
# |Tsz3650422c|   1.0|   0.0|    0.0|
# |Tsz3650419c|   1.0|   0.0|    0.0|
# |Tsz3650423c|   0.0|   0.0|    1.0|
# |Tsz3650420c|   0.0|   1.0|    0.0|
# |Tsz3650421c|   1.0|   0.0|    0.0|
# +-----------+------+------+-------+
```

where `avg((col("Status") == level).cast("double"))` is a fraction of records where column has specific value. You can find additional details in [Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe with Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900726/8371915)

You can also pivot and compute counts as shown here [percentage count per group and pivot with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40805808/8371915).

Comment: I'm getting values like 0.85, 0.14. Can you explain the above logic?

Comment: This looks like a numerical precision thing.

Comment: No. Its a not a numerical precision thing. Is it possible to get values 85.67 & 14.33 instead of 0.8567 & 14.33 so that to represent % out of 100

Comment: Just multiply by 100.